# How to scrape Eventbrite for events with PHP, given location and search terms

Tags: php, ajax, web-scraping, cookies

Two problems, really:

1.The website is dynamic. I tried using chromes developer tools to analyse the network traffic and I basically got nowhere.

2.I can't use selenium etc because I'm on a shared host and can't install anything with composer.

The AJAX requests I saw on eventbrite were baffling. I saw some requests return event data, but I don't understand how the search terms and location were sent to the server, I couldn't see them being passed in any request data, I don't know what I'm missing here? I don't know if it's done with cookies or something?

**I'd be very grateful if someone could explain how to send a location and search terms to an eventbrite endpoint to retrieve event IDs based on search terms.**

Then I can use their public API to get information for each event, given the IDs.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try selenium or webdriver-based scrapper libraries?

Comment: @KoalaYeung No, I can't install anything on the web server

Answer (score 0):

If you check [Eventbrite API documentation](https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/api#/reference/event/list), they currently only support 3 modes of event listing:

- List Event by Venue
- List Event by Organization
- List Event by Series

That means there is no stable way to retrieve all events from Eventbrite.

Two possible ways forward:

1. There might be some private API calls on Eventbrite main site. But there is no guarantee that it is stable. And there will never be documentation on how they works. There might also be a lack of feature that you want (e.g. specify your location). Just check your browser visiting the site and read every request-response.
2. It might be possible to scrap their frontpage with selenium or webdriver-based scrapper libraries, which runs browser software to run all the site's javascript for real before reading the DOM. But again the HTML could be changed frequently.

   If your hosting server do not support software installation (i.e. headless browser), find a way to do this on a local machine or virtual machine with more freedom. Then push your result to your server software somehow.